# Expected maximum bin load, for balls in bins with equal number of balls and bins

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms, chernoff-bounds

Suppose we have $n$ balls and $n$ bins. We put the balls into the bins randomly. If we count the maximum number of balls in any bin, the expected value of this is  $\Theta(\ln n/\ln\ln n)$. How can we derive this fact? Are Chernoff bounds helpful?

Comment: It is *not* true that the maximum number of balls that can go into a bin is $\log n/\log\log n$. The maximum number of balls that can go into a bin is $n$. The *expected* maximum bin load is $\Theta(\log n/\log\log n)$.

Comment: How to prove max bin load using chernoff bound ?

Answer (score 6):

The correct approximation here is Poisson. The occupancy of each bin is distributed roughly $P(1)$ (Poisson with expectation $1$), and tail bounds for Poisson random variables show that with probability $1-1/n^2$ (say), the variable is at most $O(\log n/\log\log n)$. A union bound shows that with high probability, all bins contain at most $O(\log n/\log\log n)$ balls.

A good resource on balls and bins is ["Balls into Bins" – A Simple and Tight
Analysis](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/math/balls-into-bins.pdf) by Raab and Steger. They use elementary methods to a range of $m$ (balls) and $n$ (bins) that covers the classical case $m = n$.

Comment: Can i get a more detailed solution ?

Comment: Look at the paper. It has a very detailed solution.